# MVC Core 3.0 redirect changes domain part of URL

Tags: iis, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have a controller action method that redirects a user to a url (i.e. google.com/page.html).  This works as expected in my local environment: `return Redirect();` redirects to the correct location.  However when deployed to the test environment, the Redirect() method sends the user to the correct page but the *current* domain.  Example: My website runs on mywebsite.com.  I redirect using `return Redirect("google.com/page1.html")`, but (in the test environment) it redirects the user to **http://mywebsite.com**/page1.html.  Could this be related to IIS somehow?

```
siteUrl = "https://google.com/page1.html";
return Redirect(siteUrl);     // Redirects to mywebsite.com/page1.html
```

Comment: can you share all the relevant bits of your code that exhibit this behavior? Also, does it work if you add http:// to the redirect url string?

Comment: http:// was removed for simplicity. I'll add the code but not much to show

Comment: and that siteUrl value doesn't get altered based on environment? Is there any URL rewriting setup in the project (like outlined here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/url-rewriting?view=aspnetcore-3.1 )

Comment: There are no rewrite pipelines in setup.cs other than RedirectHttps().  This should be the same URL in my local environment and Test.  The URL is actually returned from a Web api method, but the api log shows the same URL was returned both locally and in Test correctly.

Comment: Please check your log trace if it has been changed the request url.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into this same issue and ultimately found that it was caused by a setting in the IIS Application Request Routing options that is checked by default. We're using ARR for rewriting a *inbound* URLs, but didn't have *any* outbound rules so I didn't think it could be the cause if this behavior. However, there is a checkbox labelled "Reverse rewrite host in response headers" that is checked by default and will cause this behavior. Unchecking this option fixed the issue for me.